# (Android Studio 2) Could not access the Package Manager (No emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

When building the app, it builds fine, but when it comes to installing the app, it's not working.

This is my log when building and trying to install the app.

```
10/29 20:17:47: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\(Removed)\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.(Removed).myfirstapp
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.(Removed).myfirstapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.(Removed).myfirstapp
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.(Removed).myfirstapp
Unknown failure (Failure)
Error while Installing APK
```

The (Removed)'s are my computers name(Not actually, just don't want to spread its real name on the internet)

Now before you go and answer "Unlock your phone!" or "Type adb stop-server", I will list you what I have tried so far.

- Restarted the ADB server
- **UNLOCKED** my phone
- Restarted my phone
- Restarted Android Studio
- Restarted my laptop
- "Clean build" the project
- ADB devices does show my device(can browse it's files in the explorer)
- - Turned on/off the "Instant Run" thing

My code is the Hello World when creating a new project or activity, nothing changed(Not even the IDE(Fresh Install)). I would love it if someone would help me answer this question as for all the other answers have to do with an emulator(Which none of the answers worked).

Comment: By the way, your laptop stats are very unlikely related to the issue.

Comment: what is the output of adb devices?

Comment: i have  same  problem i still  investigate , if  i find solution  i will  post  it here

Android studio  : 2.3.3 
Device : S6Edge on Android 8.0

Comment: Anybody found solution ???